# Python: With Int Superclass getting TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

Tags: python

With the below code, I am getting the following error:

```
class C4(int):
    def __init__(self,name1,name2):
        self.name1=name1
        self.name2=name2
```

When above code is executed, I get the error:

```
C4_inst=C4(3,6)
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

When I only use one parameter for`__init__`, I don't see the error. Can you please shed some light on why python would try to convert the parameters to `int` when the objective here is to instantiate C4 with 3,6.
I am trying to make C4 as the subclass to "int", so that i can use the operators defined for "int" type in Class C4.

Comment: why do you inherit from int, what are you trying to achive?

Comment: Well i was just playing around operator overloading and wanted to see if i can just inherit from "int" to overload "__add__".

Answer (score 2):

The base `int` type is immutable, so its arguments are interpreted in its `__new__` method, rather than `__init__`. Since you haven't defined your own `__new__` method, the base class's version is being called, and it doesn't understand your arguments. An `int` can be initialized with two arguments, but the first must be a string and the second must be an integer (the base).

Try adding a `__new__` method that initializes the integer value properly:

```
class C4(int):
    def __new__(cls, name1, name2):
        return super(cls, C4).__new__(cls)  # let int.__new__ create a new value.
    def __init__(self, name1, name2):
        self.name1=name1
        self.name2=name2
```

Note that since we're not passing any arguments to `int.__new__`, our new instance will be equal to `0` (and since we don't have a `__repr__` or `__str__` method, it will also print out as `0`). If you want the object to behave like one of its `int` arguments (or some other non-zero value), you'll want to pass that along in the call to `int.__new__`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It worked with the above suggestion. Didn't realize that the new() method in superclass "int" was intercepting the "C4_inst" instance creation. Further digging into __new__ made it clear and actually just passing the params with the right format ("3",10) took care of it even without any "__new__" overloading in my class C4.

Comment: It wasn't entirely clear what the variables you were getting passed were supposed to mean, so I left my answer generic. If you just want to preserve the arguments, you can get away with only overloading `__init__` (though you probably want to add default arguments so all the `int` call types work). Note that it's sort of difficult to work with `int` subclasses, since any operator you don't overload will return a regular `int` instance rather than an instance of your custom class. It's often easier to write your class from scratch, encapsulating an `int` rather than inheriting from it.